# Finding indices in a Matlab cell

Tags: matlab

Consider in Matlab the cell `data` constructed as follows

```
clear all
Mrange=[2;4;3];
Mtot=sum(Mrange,1);
Nrange=[3;5;1];
Nsize=size(Nrange,1); %size(Nrange,1)=size(Mrange,1) by construction

data=cell(Nsize,1);
positions=cumsum(Mrange);
for n=1:Nsize
    if n==1    
       data{n} = kron((1 : 1 : Mrange(n))',ones(Nrange(n),1));
    else
       data{n} = kron((positions(n-1)+1 : 1 : positions(n-1)+Mrange(n))',ones(Nrange(n),1));
    end
end

%In short
%data{1} is a vector of dimension 2x3 listing [1;1;1;2;2;2] 
%(2 blocks as indicated by Mrange(1) with each number repeated 3 times as indicated by Nrange(1))

%data{2} is a vector of dimension 4x5 listing [3;3;3;3;3;4;4;4;4;4;5;5;5;5;5;6;6;6;6;6] 
%(4 blocks as indicated by Mrange(2) with each number repeated 5 times as indicated by Nrange(2))

%data{3} is a vector of dimension 2x3 listing [7;8;9] 
%(3 blocks as indicated by Mrange(3) with each number repeated once as indicated by Nrange(3))
```

Suppose now I draw `Mtot` random numbers between `1` and `Mtot`

```
%Just for reproducibility suppose
indices=[2;2;1;9;8;7;2;7;1];
```

**Question:** I want to construct a cell `indicesnew` of dimension `Nsizex1` reporting 
for `n=1,...,Nsize` the numbers in `indices` contained in `data{n}` in the order in which they appear in `indices`.

Hence

```
%indicesnew{1}=[2;2;1;2;1]
%indicesnew{2}=[]
%indicesnew{3}=[9;8;7;7]
```

This code does what I want

```
indicesnew=cell(Nsize,1);
for m=1:Mtot
    for n=1:Nsize
        if ismember(indices(m),data{n})==1
            indicesnewtemp=indicesnew{n};
            indicesnew{n}=[indicesnewtemp; indices(m)];
        end
    end
end
```

Could you suggest a more efficient version possibly without loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst `cellfun` is just an internal for-loop, this will remove one of your loops and make your code much more readable. When I tested time to run (with a 10000 loops and `tic`-`toc`) on a Linux Ubuntu computer, it also ran substantially faster.

```
indicesnew = cellfun(@(x,y) {y(ismember(y,x))}, data, repmat({indices},3,1));
```